# Easy way to update all Vagrant plugins

Tags: vagrant

Is there a command that allows one to update all currently installed Vagrant plugins?

I am using the original install command to update each individually at the moment, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Vagrant >=1.5**

`vagrant plugin update`

**Vagrant <1.5**

Here is a single line command to update the installed Vagrant plugins.

`for plugin in $(vagrant plugin list | cut -f1 -d' '); do vagrant plugin install $plugin; done;`

Comment: `vagrant plugin list` may output extra warning info at the top so `cut` may not be able to handle it correctly. Hopefully `vagrant plugin update all` will be implemented soon.

Comment: This command won't work with the upgrade to Vagrant 1.4 since there is a warning about needing to remove all the plugins and reinstall them. I that an update command is added to `vagrant plugin` as @TerryWang has said.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no built-in command to achieve this. But you could for example write a little shell-script, that reads the currently installed plugins from the directory `~\.vagrant.d\gems\gems` and then runs `vagrant plugin install` for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

A very easy one-liner:

```
vagrant plugin update $(vagrant plugin list |awk '/^[:alnum:]/i {print $1}')
```

The CLI output will be (for e.g.):

```
Updating plugins: vagrant-bindfs, vagrant-hostsupdater, vagrant-share, vagrant-vbguest. This may take a few minutes...
All plugins are up to date.
```

This will fetch all plugins from `vagrant plugin list` that have an alphanumeric name.

Lower-/Uppercase does not matter – The [`awk` Regex](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html) is case *insensitive*.